# How can we split a projector projection?

Tags: multiple-monitors, projector

Here's the thing:

We wish to display the same browser window, on a wall, however, it needs to be masket only on certain points of that wall.

So, in between the wall, there will be some objects that we wish NOT to have the projector to project, like so:

------------------------ WALL ------------------------

|**content**| real flower |**content**| real flower |**content**|

We can connect a PC, with a graphic card with 3 outputs, OR we can have 3 graphic cards, with 3 projectors, and perhaps that will work but, does anyone know a way for doing this otherwise? For example, using one single projector?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried using an actual mask over the projector lens?

Comment: I haven't tried, I'm studying it. I don't have the hardware, because I need to better understand the possibilities. But, as far as I was able to think, it didn't occur to me, to actually mask the projector lens themselves! Do you thing it's worth trying?

Comment: But perhaps the projected area, is not wide enough for a single projector.

Comment: Well none of us are there to measure it so...

Comment: The area to be projected should be around 3m wide and 2m heigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masking the projector lens will not work because you will end up with blurred boundaries, the mask would have to be at a point where the image is focused, either inside the projector, or at the wall, unless you rigged up some fancy external lens system with a mask at a point where the image was focused then a second lens to focus the image on the wall which is not very practical.

You could try to simply overlay 2 black bars on the content you wish to display on the wall as black on a projector is the absence of projected light(in ideal conditions). In practice there would be some light bleed but it would be similar to shining a light on the wall. You may even want to try white bars which would light up the flowers but still block the website content at that point.

To make the bars you may need to create a program that can display its window on top of the window you are using to show the website, a simple c# application could probably do this and would not require much coding knowledge.

Comment: Sorry Dan, I don't totally understand the bars part of it. Do you suggest we create black bars on the place we wish to display the actual content, and that those bars could overlay the content somehow?

Comment: No you would overlay black bars where you wish not to display the content.

Comment: Let's say: I would create an image, and place that image on the browser. Then, I would need to overlay the sections of that image with some black bars. The result would be that of displaying the content of a given area, except the place where the black bars are, is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. There will still be some light bleed, even when the projector is projecting black a small amount of light will still be emitted. Black on a projector is created by blocking light output. White is full light output from the bulb and colors are blocking specific frequencies of light. A projector works by shining a really bright light through an image and onto a wall. The color black is created by blocking as much of this light as possible.

Comment: Dan, and why do we need the overlay? Wouldn't the draw of black elements of the video or image edition be enough?

Comment: Yes it should be, I just did not know if you were creating the content or using content from someone else